# Android screen reader says "Dismiss" when targetting flutter drawer

Tags: android, dart, flutter, accessibility

I'm developing an app using Flutter, and I want to make sure it is accessible.

I have a drawer that I'm using as a navigation menu. When it is open and I use the screen reader the screen reader reads out: "Dismiss", "Home", "Conversations". I tried adding a semanticLabel, but it does not get read.

[Here's a picture of the app and where I'm targeting with the screen reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0gwt.png)

I want it to read out that the navigation menu is open, or at least change the "Dismiss" to something more informative like "Close navigation menu".

Where can I edit the "Dismiss" text, or where else can I add screen readable text to the drawer so users know when it is open?

My code for the drawer is as such:

```dart
Scaffold(
        endDrawer: SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: Drawer(
              semanticLabel: "Navigation Menu",
              child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Home"),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Conversations"),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                )
              ],
            ))),
       appBar: AppBar(
       ...
```